# Raspbain G++ Compiler stopping on --m commands

Tags: linux, g++, scons, raspbian

> Blockquote

Hello, I am trying to compile the latest source of The Powder Toy  but my compiler (G++ with scons) is crashing every time it hits a command with --m in it.

Crash log:

```
scons --lin --release --sse2
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C library fftw3f... (cached) yes
Checking for C library bz2... (cached) yes
Checking for C library z... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file bzlib.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library lua... (cached) no
Checking for C library lua5.1... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
^[[Ag++ -o build/src/Format.o -c -w -std=c++98 -fkeep-inline-functions -sse2 -O3 -ftree-vectorize -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffast-math -fomit-frame-pointer -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DLUACONSOLE -DGRAVFFT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DUSE_STDINT -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DUSE_SDL -DLIN -DX86 -DX86_SSE2 -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -Ibuild/src -Ibuild/data -Ibuild/generated build/src/Format.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized option â-msse2â
scons: *** [build/src/Format.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Why would this be happening? I've had to delete the -m32 command also to get it to compile.

Comment: Can you show the related SCons scripts, please.

Comment: Also, what version of g++ are you using? If you execute the g++ commands on the command line manually (without SCons) does it still crash? If so, then it has nothing to do with SCons.

Comment: g++ (Debian 4.6.3-12+rpi1) 4.6.3
Yes, if I use G++ on the comamnd line without scons it crashes on the -m32 command

Comment: I added the raspbian tag, lets see if one of the raspberry experts knows something about this problem. It sounds like a TR (error report) needs to be created on the gcc compiler for raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that it's because the -sse2 option is telling g++ to generate [SSE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2), which are SIMD instructions for Intel's x86 architecture.  The Raspberry Pi board is a completely different computer architecture (ARM) and does not support SSE2.  The ARM equivalent of SSE2 is NEON, but NEON is available for the ARM used in RPi.

I think that for options that g++ doesn't recognize, it tries prefixing with another flag (in this case -m, but I've seen -f before) to see if it's a synonym.

In your case sse2 makes no sense on the Raspberry Pi, and for the above example, is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

What is ^[[A ? Do you have unprintable chars in your makefile? Can you echo all parameters one by one to identify which contains these strange characters?

Comment: He probably hit a key while it was compiling.

Comment: There are no makefiles involved here, but instead SCons. This isnt an answer. These sorts of questions should be left as a comment on the original question.

Comment: Yea, I probably hit an arrow key during the compile accidentally. There isn't any invisible characters in the SConscript, and the only way I've got it to compile is to # out the lines with --m32. This is the do a proper compile and it errors on the line env.Append(CCFLAGS='-msse2')